# Managing Session Variable in View Page After Session Expire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-state, asp.net-session

I have to manage a session variable in the view page after session expire
In controller

```
public ActionResult See()
{
   Session["Name"] = "Mani";
   return View();
}
```

In view

```
@if(Session["Name"] != null)
{
    Session["Name"]
}
```

I works fine until Session Expire. But when session expires it shows error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Inex.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

How to logout the user when the session expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a try catch and redirect back to login page in catch ...
this is also a good way to check for null exceptions..

In your View

```
@try{
       <p>@Session["Name"].ToString()</p>
}
catch(Exception)
{

}
```

No need to check with an if else .. also when an exception occurs it will go to catch and application will continue without breaking if any redirect is not made .. if you feel session is expired redirect the user to the login page ..

Comment: my question is to show `session variable` in view page

Comment: use try catch in view page ?? Prevents exception

Comment: @try{
  Session["Name"].ToString()
}
Catch(Exception)
{
Redirect back somewhere 
}

Comment: in the `Catch`, `Redirect` to controller is possible

Comment: yes .. you have to use old asp.net response.redirect

Comment: Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index"); // Home controller and Index action